# Multiply an insert in database from php

Tags: php, database, insert

I have a php that inserts a number to my database. I would like that every value of 1 should be 0,01 in the database so if a person enters 50 it will be inserted as 0,5 in the database. This means i have to multiply the number from the php with 0,01. Is this possible? I have this code which insert the number to the database `$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (score) values('$points');";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should probably look into mysqli, which will grant you safer interaction with mysql.

You could solve your problem like this though:

```
 $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (score) VALUES ('%s');", $DB_Table, $points * 0,01);
```

In mysqli the corresponding would be something like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $DB_Table (score) VALUES (?);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $point * 0,01);
$stmt->execute();
```

This helps you avoid SQL injection and the such. 
Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $DB_Table (`score`) VALUES('" . ($points*0.01) ."');";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (score) values('" . ($points / 100) . "');"
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (score) values('".($points / 100)."');";
```

Also you don't mention what datatype your field is; I believe decimal is what you need, not int